# Missing directory in IntelliJ IDEA 12

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm my project tree, the compilation directory for Tomcat '/WEB-INF/classes' is not visible. I would like to access it so I can deploy specific compiled *.class files to a remote host.

I've checked both the File Types -> Ignored Files and Compiler -> Excludes and there's nothing there that would hide the directory. I also checked git and it's not excluded there.

Does IntelliJ hide the compilation directory by default in the project tree? Is there a way to make it visible?

Comment: Output directory is hidden and you can't enable it. Additional classes and libraries should be [added to the artifact instead](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-artifacts.html).

Comment: Ok, it seems strange because you can deploy to a remote server, and the compiled java in "classes" would be among the things usually deployed, if using an exploded web app. You can deploy "WEB-INF" and it will upload everything in it, including 'classes'.